JPA Criteria Query for my Movie Collection
I have a huge (I mean: HUGE) collection of movies and a cute website to track titles. Each movie in the database has a record in table “movies” with a lot of fields but for this problem, two fields are the most important: id (primary key),and dateAdd (indexed, non-unique pure DATA  field that holds date (without time) when the movie was added to collection).
I want to check how my collection grew over time. I want a list of dates, starting from the date when the first movie was added ant the number of movies that I had on that date. Dates when nothing happened (no movie was added)can be skipped.
I have an SQL for it, and there are several ways to do the same thing with varying times of execution.
I want:
a) The fastest query (MySQL) :)
b) Query implementation using JPA Criteria API, ready to be used in a SpringBoot project.
Anyone interested to give it a try?
SQL part is easy, JPA is driving me nuts.

SELECT
DATE(dateAdded) AS date,
COUNT() AS movies_added,
SUM(COUNT()) OVER (ORDER BY DATE(dateAdded)) AS cumulative_movies_added
FROM Movies
GROUP BY DATE(dateAdded)
ORDER BY DATE(dateAdded);
is this the output you need.
